# How to make a Varchar column GETDATE() actual?

Tags: date, sql-server-2000

My SQL Server 2000 is getting a old date.

I got a column `out__days VARCHAR` that when people register in my website this column put the date in there like (`2003-11-21`)

I need to put the actual date there aways, but I try `GETDATE()` and nothing.

Some one got a solution for this crazy thing?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATETIME` datatype!

Comment: The server files need like, so, i am tring to do this

Comment: UPDATE MEMB_INFO
SET out__days = 2013-12-25
WHERE out__days = 2003-11-23
AND out__days > 2013-12-25

but it says to me ( Server: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Syntax error converting the varchar value '2003-11-23' to a column of data type int. )